# How to create a new module in existing project?

Tags: symfony1

In symfony, how to create new module in existing project.
I created new module in schema.yml files.but the page goes to home page.
then how to add new database?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried reading the [Symfony docs](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/)? Great place to start. To answer you direct question check out [Day 3 of the Jobeet Tutorial](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/03), halfway down the page is how to create a new module. Note, these links are too the doctrine version, if you need Propel start [here](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Propel/en/).